# Why is my app being run on emulators - should I worry?

Tags: android, emulation

While tracking Google Play Services exceptions in my app (code 2 and 9), I notice that my app is being run by emulators every day: For example, "QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)", "Batmobile XT320", or "unknown AOSP on ARM Emulator".

These emulators even sometimes run older versions seconds after running the current version, and they never really use the app properly. They constantly reinstall the app and run it multiple times.

I have already implemented an emulator check and finish the activity when detected (although I am allowing TrendMicro TMMARS app reputation engine).

What are the emulators really doing, and should I worry about this?